# MVC3 : data retrived from ViewData contains "/"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a small problem. I'm passing a id from one view to another.
I do it like this:

```
@Html.Partial("DetailViews/_Parameters", Model.Parameters, new ViewDataDictionary { { "data-resourceId", Model.Id } })
```

I use this id for a hidden field in a form on the partial view. like this:

```
<form id="formAddNewParameter" action"#" title="Add new Parameter">
    <input type="hidden" name="resourceId" id="resourceId" class="required" rel="0" value=@ViewData["data-resourceId"]/>
</form>
```

The ID is passed as it should. BUT there is always a "/" at the end...
Anyone know where this "/" comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the qutation marks `""` around the `value` tag's value

```
<form id="formAddNewParameter" action"#" title="Add new Parameter">
    <input type="hidden" name="resourceId" 
           id="resourceId" class="required" rel="0" 
           value="@(ViewData["data-resourceId"])" />
</form>
```

And I guess the tag closing `/` somehow mixed into the value tag.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.